# How to restrict the AutoCompleteTextView dropdown dismiss on text change listener?

Tags: android

I take the autocomplete textview and it's change liseter event.

When I enter the text in it, the pop up fill with data with adapter, when I again enter one more character, it dismiss and reopen again. I don't want to dismiss it. It remain open when I enter character one by one and it change data in adapter.

XML :

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autoTextSearch"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/search_bg"
            android:completionThreshold="1"
            android:dropDownHeight="360dp"
            android:dropDownHorizontalOffset="-140dp"
            android:dropDownVerticalOffset="0dp"
            android:dropDownWidth="400dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxWidth="105dp"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:popupBackground="@drawable/popup_search"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp" >
        </AutoCompleteTextView>
```

And adapter set :

```
DropdownListAdapter dropdownListAdapter = new DropdownListAdapter(context, R.layout.row_search, arrListSearch);
        textView.setAdapter(dropdownListAdapter);
        textView.showDropDown();
```

Comment: I guess the problem is with your on text change listener. check ehat function u call there

Comment: seems its a default behaviour, why to change it?

Comment: But i can't get defaultly the pop up open...if i remove the showdropdown then i can't get dropdown popup.

Comment: please see the xml that i have taken for drop down pop up

Comment: what do you mean? why do you call textView.showDropDown();?

Comment: means i write the character in auto complete textview and open the drop down form it..please see the drop down bg that i have set..So i want that it opens only one time and not dismiss when i change the text.

Comment: Please check it and help me.....I have put my full code here

Comment: see setDropDownAlwaysVisible in https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java, note "@hide Pending API council approval" in the javadocs

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51229/discussion-between-denny-sharma-and-pskink)